# How to set break points on all destructors in AIX? (c++)

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints, aix, dbx

I have found that rbreak in gdb can do this by a regular expression.
Is there an alternative way in aix dbx?
I have read [the document of IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/dbx.htm).
It seems that dbx cannot do this.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/dbx/entry/gdb_vs_dbx_commands_mapping  gdb: rbreak regex dbx: - 
Note: need to use funcs command and manually set breakpoints with “stop in”   dbx
- 
Note: need to use funcs command and manually set breakpoints with “stop in”

Comment: Thanks @M.Dogru **"funcs"** is available in oracle AIX. I wonder if there is an alternative way in IBM AIX?